# How to pass ArrayList<Coordinate[]> from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, android-intent

I have tried all day to do this and haven't had any luck. I have an ArrayList with an Array of Coordinate types inside, and I want to pass this from one activity to another. I don't think this is possible through using Intent. So I am wondering what other option do I have? I want something simple..

Comment: Make a singleton class and keep the list in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably put the values in a database in your first activity and only pass some unique identifier on to the second activity so it can recreate the ArrayList on the other side.  But if you want a quick solution, use the intent bundle and serialize/deserialize the coordinates yourself:

```
ArrayList<Coordinate> mCoords = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

private void startOtherActivity()
{
    int numCoords = mCoords.size();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("coord_size", numCoords);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCoords; i++)
    {
        Coordinate coord = mCoords.get(i);
        intent.putExtra("coord_x_" + i, coord.getX());
        intent.putExtra("coord_y_" + i, coord.getY());
    }

    //start other activity...
}
```

Then grab the values out of the bundle on the other side and regen the ArrayList.

Edit: Just realized you're talking about Coordinate[]s.  Same principle still applies, just nest another for loop in there and keep track of each individual array's length as well.

Update: On the other side, you'd have something like

```
int len = intent.getIntegerExtra("coord_size", 0);
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    float x = intent.getFloatExtra("coord_x_" + i, 0.0);
    float y = intent.getFloatExtra("coord_y_" + i, 0.0);
    mCoords.add(new Coordinate(x, y));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this example however how do you unpack it in the other activity. You cant say intent.getCoordinateExra("coord_x", coord.x)

Comment: Added the other side.  Btw, are you aware of the Point and PointF classes?  They're pretty good for coordinates, unless you have some need for a custom Coordinate class.

Comment: excellent. Thank you for this. Yes i have seen and used Point too

Answer (score 0):

You can have a singleton "Model" class, on which you can store the ArrayList object from one activity, and retrieve it from another.

Comment: do you mind explaining more on how i can do this please? Do you mean making a custom application class so the arraylist lasts for the lifetime of the app and can be accessed anytime? because if so i tried this however it is not dynamic enough. I will be making many of these ArrayList<Coordinate[]> and i'd really need to override them for the different things i am making

Comment: Then, you are better off splitting your application into M-V-C. The Activity class is the View. You can create plain Java classes for M & C. Describing how to implement an MVC pattern in Android is beyond the scope of a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create Bundle and try to put the ArrayList. Then send the bundle in the intent.

Comment: i tried but you cannot put an ArrayList of type Coordinate[] into a bundle

Answer (score 0):

You could write a ParcelableCoordinate class that implements Parcelable, and then have it convert the Coordinate objects into ParcelableCoordinate objects, put them in the intent, and then do the reverse on the other side.